# Writing a cross framework class, ConfigurationManager and ConfigurationSettings

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-2.0, web-config, .net-1.1

I'm trying to write a little web.config reading class, and want it to be available for all .net framework solutions I am writing.

Everything is going fine, except for .net 1.1 and below I need to use System.configuration.configurationsettings.appsettings and for after 1.1 am using
System.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.

This is a bit frustrating at the minute, and I want to figure out is there a way to do the following pseudo code

```
if environment.version.major < 2 then
  use configurationsettings.appsettings
else
  use configurationmanager.appsettings.
end if
```

I tried a little of using type.gettype to get around it, but I thought this must be such a simple fix, that someone else has a neat answer.

Comment: Most of us solved this problem by upgrading. .NET 4.0 is now in Release Candidate. You're still using .NET 1.1. Hint, hint.

Comment: lol, not my choice mate. got legacy apps to support. we can't all be trail blazers. The newest version of the solution is in 3.5 but I don't have the choice to ditch the 1.1 version either. 
I can get around it, but I'm pernickety.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do it by entering a flag in VS, go to project properties, in build option, conditional compilation symbols which you could enter a value like aspnet11 or aspnet2, and then you can do conditional code in your app like:

```
#if aspnet11

#elseif aspnet2

#else

#endif
```

And so you can build multiple versions of your library for multiple frameworks...

HTH.